# Show iAd when Internet connection is restored?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iad

When there's no Internet connection, my delegate's `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` gets called.

However, when the Internet connection is restored, my `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` never gets called, as opposed to being called every 30 seconds or so as long as the Internet hasn't been disconnected.

Is there a way to restore iAd ads when the Internet gets reconnected?

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't ask how to detect if Internet is back, I asked how to make iAd generate Ads again. As opposed to AdMob, iAd doesn't have a Refresh or Reload method, to the best of my Knowledge.